# Can noise cancellation be explained with a particle model of air?

Tags: acoustics

If you think about air as a bunch of particles, and a speaker at one end of the room is causing compression waves, how is a speaker at some other point supposed to add compression waves to stop the other compression waves from hitting the opposite wall??? Or if you think about it with just two people and two balls and one person throws a ball at a wall, I don't see how the second person is going to stop the ball from hitting the wall by throwing their ball at the first ball. If anything you get more collisions at the wall, i.e. the ear drum.. yet they still sell noise cancellation head phones....

Comment: Pressure is due to the collisions of the molecules, a sound wave is a pressure wave on top of the ambient pressure, this is due to the slow period oscillation in the rate of the molecular collisions, these oscillations have a phase and amplitude and they can cancel each other out. You're then left with the ambient rate of collisions, which is just the atmospheric pressure.

Comment: The properties of continuous fluid model are more or less all amenable to explanation in terms of atomic models. The place to start is with "the kinetic theory of gases" (which is fairly tractable even for beginning students) and then on into statistical mechanics (which takes a bit more preparation).

Comment: And yes you have those particles, but sound waves are waves of densities or pressure, and you can analyze it from the wave point of view. In that realm the density or pressure that waves is due to so many particles you can use a continuous approximation. And yes you can have phonons defined which are the photon equivalents, if you have those equivalent discrete effects.